# how can i find use the Jquery select that seleted option textvalue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find select tag's textvalue to use node .:)
I made that div container is addable.
that contains `<span>` and `<select>`

```
<div class="selector" style="width: 140px;">

    <span style="width: 128.4px; -webkit-user-select: none;">::before</span>

          <select id="category0" name="category" class="category">

            <option selected="selected" value="0">Select a category</option>

            <option value="0">All</option>

            <option value="01">TOMATO</option>

            <option value="02">APPLE</option>

            <option value="03">BANANA</option>

        </select>

</div>
```

All `<div>` containers name is category. 
I want to add value that selected `<option>` tags text.(not value ex)BANANA)

```
$(document).on("change","[name='category']",function(){

  //$(this) means <select>tag

    $(this).prev().html( "I want to contain selected options text" );

});
```

I tried this and failed...:(...

```
       $(this).children().each(function(index,item){

            if(item.attr("value")==findval){

            testop=item.text();

            }

            });

        $(this).prev().html(testop);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find('option:selected')` to find the selected `option` element. `.text()` will return the `textContent` of the selected element. [[Ref](https://api.jquery.com/find/)]

```js
$(document).on("change", "[name='category']", function() {
  var textOfOption = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $(this).prev().html(textOfOption);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="width: 128.4px; -webkit-user-select: none;">::before</span>
<select id="category0" name="category" class="category">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">Select a category</option>
  <option value="0">All</option>
  <option value="01">TOMATO</option>
  <option value="02">APPLE</option>
  <option value="03">BANANA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rayon Dabre :)!!!!! but I can't fix the problem
I have tried for more than five hours. now I succeeded thanks to you

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__